# Micromax Unite 2 A106, app installation error

Tags: insufficient-memory

When I'm installing an app it show internal storage insufficient space. But the internal SD memory has lots of space, approx 5gb free.

Please give me a solution.

Comment: try moving some apps(Games or system) into the external SD card.

Answer (score 1):

In micromax Unite 2 out of 8 GB internal memory only 1 GB is allotted for installing Applications. With default applications and their updates it takes around 700 MB so you must have already exhausted the allotted 1 GB for applications.

Try uninstalling some unnecessary updates or try rooting.

Comment: How will rooting the fone help in rectifying installatn error?

Comment: In case of error caused by not having sufficient space, you can free up space by uninstalling lot of preloaded apps like Mad, micro max live etc. Which are really useless. This can be uninstalled only if you have root access. Further you can reparation your phone such a way that space allotted for apps can be increased by eg 1 GB which will in turn reduce general storage by 1 GB.