# Can't install apps!! OUT OF SPACE error!! HTC DESIRE 626

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, htc-desire, htc, cache

I'm using HTC Desire 626. I have more than 2 GB space left on Phone Storage. But I can't install any more apps or games. It's saying that my phone is out of space.

[image]

I've tried cleaning up all kind of cache files. But no luck!

Please help me out! This problem is driving me mad.

Comment: Can you please say whether or not you are rooted, as well as if you have an SD Card.  If you do have an SD Card, please note how much space it has.

Comment: My phone is rooted and I don't have any SD card

Comment: Get an SD Card.  Since you are rooted, you can move apps quite easily to this SD Card by going to the application manager and clicking "Move to SD Card".

Answer (score 1):

(from an Android 4.4.4 user on a Nexus 7 2013)

I began to have this problem after installing the Xposed module "XInstaller". I uninstalled that module and everything went back to normal.

Important: It can get easy to confuse all of these X words. It wasn't "Xposed Installer" that was the issue. The issue was the module for Xposed called "XInstaller". This module lets you change some of Android's default app installation/uninstallation behaviors. For now, I'm leaving that module alone.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue with my micromax mobile.
Issue in my case was only 890 mb was available for installing apps. Even though there was around 4.5 Gb free space in phone memory. Your issue seems to be same as mine. What you have to do is to  reparation the phone memory so as to allocate more space for installing the apps. Downside is whatever memory allocated for apps can only be used for installing apps. You cannot store photos or music in it . further your phone should be routed. Repartitioning procedure for your phone may be available in net.
Check if your phone has separate internal SD card.
I had repartitioned to increase app memory to 2.5 GB.
I am attaching link with similar issue.

[Micromax Unite 2 A106, app installation error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84190/micromax-unite-2-a106-app-installation-error)

Comment: That makes sense. But I don't know how to repartition the phone memory and allocate more space for installing apps. Btw my phone is ROOT-ed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is not the lack of space but the google Play app that doesn't work properly. If you really have free space in your phone, try to download any APK and install it (You might need to activate the option "Unknown Sources" from security settings)....if that doesn't work either.....Try to clear Cache/Data for Google Play app and see if that works.